# dynamic sql query using jquery + php

Tags: php, jquery, sql, postgresql

Just wondering if anyone can point me in the directuon of some tutorial/s that
Delve into sql queries/insertions/deletions (is that a word?) using jquery and/or php.

What I was specifically wanting to do was have a button that added an entry to a table
And then the button would change or dissappear or become greyed out.

Any links that might set me on the right track would be awesome!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can also reffer to CRUD which stands for Create, Read, Update & Delete. To answer you answer you could always make a ajax call to a php file and pass in some parameters. The php file would then query to the database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143191/inserting-into-mysql-from-php-jquery-ajax

Comment: you dont need php nor database to do this, unless you want that table row to be populated with data from a database

Answer (score 1):

http://agiletoolkit.org/intro/addons

Scroll down for a CRUD implementation using jQuery UI dialog on top of [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like achieved in jQuery UI dialog modal-form.
In the other end, you just sanitize input and make modifications.
It would be awesome, if you give more exact description of what you want achieve.