# Insert records into mysql database without reloading page

Tags: mysql, database

What is the most simple way to insert values into a mysql database without reloading the page? In this particular example, I'd like to have a form with one input field, and when the form is submitted, the user's input to the field is inserted into a mysql database table, but the page is not reloaded.

Comment: You would have to submit the data via Ajax.  Once the browser itself submits the form it is expecting a response from the server with a new page to be displayed.

Comment: I think you're mising the programming language/platform you use for your front-end/web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to send content to a server side file (without reloading) and that file can insert row(s) in the database. Here's an example : http://www.9lessons.info/2009/08/vote-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html Here, this guy creates a digg like vote button and it inserts and updates rows without reloading the page. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Look at jquery ajax() or the jquery.form() plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This requires AJAX.

You CAN do this with plain JS, but jQuery makes your life a lot easier.

See this post for a good example:

[Inserting into MySQL from PHP (jQuery/AJAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143191/inserting-into-mysql-from-php-jquery-ajax)