# pass parameters from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this jquery script

```
$(function() { // <----doc ready starts
    $("#btn1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#id1").val(); 
        var last_name = $("#id2").val();
        var dataString = {'name=':name, 'last_name': last_name};
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://localhost/insert.php',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this php one inserting parameters from the first script into mysql database:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','os');

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table_info (name, name2) VALUES($name, $last_name)");

    if ($insert_row){
        print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />'; 
    }
    else {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
    }
    $mysqli->free();
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

When I'm trying to run it, it is failing with that error:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 3
>       Notice: Undefined index: last_name in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 4
>       Error : (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' )' at line 1

What's wrong here, sorry for stupid question, this is my first experience with php and jQuery both.

Answer (score 6):

You're not providing your `dataString` variable to the AJAX call, so no data is being sent. You need to add it in the `data` property of `$.ajax`:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#id1").val(); 
    var last_name = $("#id2").val();
    var dataString = { 'name': name, 'last_name': last_name };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://localhost/insert.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Note that I also fixed the `name=` typo in the object definition.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the valid `dataString`.Try with -

```
var dataString = "{'name=':"+name+", 'last_name': "+last_name+"}";
```

And pass it to the call -

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://localhost/insert.php',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read from `$_POST` but you are making a GET request.

JSONP is, by specification, **always** GET. You cannot make a POST request using that technique.

`type: 'POST',` will be ignored since you say `dataType: 'jsonp',`

---

You are also trying to read from `name` but you have called your field `name=`. You need to use the same names throughout.

---

When you get a response, you will get an error because your PHP script is not responding with JSONP.

You need to have `header("Content-Type: application/javascript");` and then something along the lines of:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($your_response) . ");";
```

… but you should add protection for [the Rosetta  vulnerability](https://miki.it/blog/2014/7/8/abusing-jsonp-with-rosetta-flash/) by sanitising the callback name.

---

Alternatively, remove `dataType: 'jsonp',` and add `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` to the PHP.

Comment: I tried that, but errors are the same, I think I'll it like it is done here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143191/inserting-into-mysql-from-php-jquery-ajax[/link]

Answer (score 0):

After this line :type: 'POST', add this line:  data:dataString,

Answer (score -2):

```
`enter code here`try to change the ajax call like this
`enter code here`$(function() { // <----doc ready starts
   `enter code here` $("#btn1").click(function(e) {
      `enter code here`  e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#id1").val(); 
        var last_name = $("#id2").val();
        var dataString = {'name=':name, 'last_name': last_name};
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://localhost/insert.php',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```