# How to insert into SQL using PHP and AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have looked at this post: [Inserting into MySQL from PHP (jQuery/AJAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143191/inserting-into-mysql-from-php-jquery-ajax) but I didn't get the code to work. It's a quite old post so it might not work anymore?

I want to insert a post from my website (PHP) into my database (MySQL) without updating the page. I'm looking at AJAX (for example the link above) but I don't understand how to get it to work.

I have also looked at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwo4fAqaVFM for loading data and that's very simple so I thought it would be as simple to insert, but it wasn't...

Can anyone help me?

This new save.php actually works.

**index.php**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>
    <form id="example" method="post">
        <input name="textbox">
        <input type="button" name="submitbuttonname" value="submit" onClick="$.post('save.php', $('form#example').serialize())">
    </form>
</body>
```

**New save.php**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','audf');
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8') or die('Charset kunde inte ändras till UTF-8');

if($db->connect_errno){
    die('Sorry, we are having some problems.');
}
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];

$db->query("INSERT INTO test_db (first_name) VALUES ('".$firstName."')");
```

**Old save.php**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','audf');
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8') or die('Charset kunde inte ändras till UTF-8');

if($db->connect_errno){
    die('Sorry, we are having some problems.');
}

if($_POST["submitbuttonname"]) {
    $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test_db (first_name) VALUES (?)");
    $q->execute(array($_POST["textbox"]));
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of examples and tutorials! Read here: http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery

Comment: just try - and post your code here if you got problems/questions.

Comment: Updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is sending the data as `$_GET`;
Add `method="POST"` to your `<form>` element.

edit: Oh. OK I didn't fully read your code:
Your form is probably being sent before it fires the $.post request.
Try changing the input type from "submit" to "button".

Regards ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still doesn't work. It won't put anything into the database. Anything in save.php that looks wrong?

Comment: You could try to display `$db->errno` after preparing the INSERT

Comment: It doesn't show anything... It's like save.php doesn't even load.

Comment: Try to open the Inspector console (right click anywhere on the page and select "Inspect" - should be similar in both FF and Chrome) and go to the Network tab. You should see a new entry each time you click on the $.post requesting button.

Comment: or you could add a third parameter to the $.post function and have it look like: 
`$.post('save.php', $('form#example').serialize(), function(res){alert(res)} )`
This way you should have an alert with the output of save.php

Comment: The network inspector showed that save.php was loaded with the POST protocol. The function returns an alert that says: Undefined index: submitbuttonname in .../save.php on line 9.

Comment: Updated the original post again. The new save.php actually works now. Do you think my changes are legit? :)

Comment: Glad you made it working. Prepared statements are considered a better practice (they're safer against SQL injections) but whatever works, works.

Answer (score 1):

For a cleaner code, I made some modifications.

**html**

```
<form id="example" method="post">
    <input name="textbox">
    <input type="button" name="submitbuttonname" value="submit">
</form>
```

**ajax using POST method to call save.php**

```
$('#example').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var frmdata = $('#example').serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    url: 'save.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : frmdata,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        alert("Saved!");
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err.responseText);
    }
});
});
```

**save.php - binding parameters lacking**

```
if($_POST["textbox"]) {
$textb = $_POST['textbox'];
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test_db (first_name) VALUES (?)");
$q->bind_param("s",$fname);
$fname = $textb;
$q->execute();

if($q){
 $array = array('data'=> $textb);
  echo json_encode($array);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The link is working until now. Something might not be working with your code. You could post a snippet of what you have tried so that we could find out what is missing. Happy Coding!

Comment: Updated the original post.